# Wordpress blog archive look like in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building and application with cakePHP and I'm trying to achieve something like Wordpress blog archive.

Let's imagine that i have this table in my database:

- Posts

  - id
  - title
  - body
  - created

and i want the output something like this:

- 2013

  - Post 1
  - Post 2
  - etc
- 2012

  - Post 4
  - Post 5
  - etc etc

I have searched and tried by myself but unfortunately with no success
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Retrieving the data? Preparing the data in the view?

Comment: hi ndm the actual problem is retrieving the data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could create a method inside your Post Model that retrieves all the posts from one specific year:

```
//Inside Model/Post.php

public function getPostsByYear($year) {

$date1 = new DateTime($year.'-01-01 00:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime($year.'-12-31 23:59:59');

$posts = $this->find('all' , array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.created BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date1,$date2)
     )
    ));

    return $posts
}
```

Then, inside the desired action in your PostsController you would iterate from any desired initial year (in my case, i chose 2012) to the current year, calling the **getPostsByYear()** method multiple times, like this:

```
//Inside Controller/PostsController.php

public function somePostAction() {

$posts = new Array();
$currentYear = date("Y");

    for($year = 2012 ; $year<=$currentYear ; $year++) {
        $posts[$year] = $this->Post->getPostsByYear($year);
    }

$this->set('posts' , $posts);

}
```

This way, for instance, all your posts from 2012 would be in the **$posts[2012]** array. If you'd like to study it's structure, just write **debug($posts)**.

Just a reminder, the code above is untested. Let me know if there's any trouble.

Comment: Brunno thank you for your answer. I made a small change in your code and then everything worked just fine. Thank you very much.

Change: 
$date1 = $year.'-01-01 00:00:00';
$date2 = $year.'-12-31 23:59:59';

Comment: I'm having troubles displaying the information the way i said in my question :S
Im using debugkit so i can see the array structure but cant get the info displayed the way i want. Ex: h1>Year p>postTitle

Comment: What is your problem exactly with displaying the info?
Is information that you need missing, or don't you know how to retrieve a specific part of the array?

Comment: @Spoke I just found a solution. Thank you very much for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a little outdated, most of the code should be re-factored to go into a model but this is exactly doing this.

https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/develop/Controller/Component/ArchiveComponent.php

Comment: I'm kinda new to cakePHP, how do i use that ArchiveComponent?